# What's the principle of autoloading in PHP?

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

`spl_autoload_register` can do this kind of job,but I don't understand how is that kind of job done?

```
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic idea is that you don't have to write `include`/`require` instructions anymore : whenever you're trying to use a non-defined class, PHP will call the autoloader.

The job of the autoloader, then, is to determine which file should be loaded, and `include` it, so the class becomes defined.

PHP can then use that class, as if you were the one who wrote the `include` instruction, that has in fact been executed in the autoloading function.

The "trick" is that the autoloading function :

- only receives the name of the class
- has to determine which file to load -- i.e. which file contains that class.

This is the reason for naming convention, such as the PEAR one, which says that class such as `Project_SubProject_Component_Name` are mapped to files such as `Project/SubProject/Component/Name.php` -- i.e. '`_`' in the class names are replaces by slashes *(directories, subdirectories)* on the filesystem.

For instance, if you take a look at the `Doctrine_Core::autoload` method, which is the one that will be called as an autoloader in your case, it contains this portion of code *(after dealing with some specific cases)* :

```
$class = self::getPath() 
            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
            str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) 
            . '.php';
if (file_exists($class)) {
    require $class;
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Which means the class name's is mapped to the filesystem, replacing '`_`' by '`/`', and adding a final `.php` to the file name.

For instance, if you're trying to use the `Doctrine_Query_Filter_Chain` class, and it is not known by PHP, the `Doctrine_Core::autoload` function will be called ; it'll determine that the file that should be loaded is `Doctrine/Query/Filter/Chain.php` ; and as that file exists, it'll be included -- which means PHP now "knows" the `Doctrine_Query_Filter_Chain` class.

Comment: What if there are many classes registered,will all of them be executed or only the one matching `Doctrine`?

Comment: If you have several autoloading functions registered with `spl_autoload_register`, you'll have a "queue" of autoloading functions. PHP will *(quoting http://www.php.net/spl_autoload_register )* "run through each of them in the order they are defined" ;;; which means the first funtion will be called ; if the class still doesn't exist, the second will be called ; and so on -- independanty of the class name.

Comment: To add a bit of information to my previous comment : the `"Doctrine"` string you are using only means that the autoloading function that you are registering is the static method `autoload` in the `Doctrine` class *(see "callback" here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php )* ;;; it doesn't say anything about what classes that autoloader will be able to autoload.

Comment: I followed that link,seems `spl_autoload_register` doesn't accept an array as parameter,but why the above still works?

Comment: `spl_autoload_register` accepts a *"callback"* as its first parameter ; and an array containing a classname as first element, and a static method name as second element is a valid callback -- see the link I posted in my second comment.